# Algorithm for matrix addition and multiplication

Tags: algorithm, matrix, time, big-o, matrix-multiplication

Let m, n be integers such that 0<= m,n< N.

Define:

```
  Algorithm A: Computes m + n in time O(A(N))

  Algorithm B: Computes m*n in time O(B(N))

  Algorithm C: Computes m mod n in time O(C(N))
```

Using any combination of algorithms A, B and C describe an algorithm for N X N matrix addition and matrix multiplication with entries in Z/NZ. Also indicate the algorithm's run time big-O notation.

Attempt at solution:

For N X N addition in Z/NZ:
Let A, and B be N X N matrices in Z/NZ with entries a_{ij} and b_{ij} such that i,j in {0,1,...,N} where i represents the row and j represents the column in the matrix. Also, let A + B = C

```
Step 1. Run Algorithm A to get a_{ij} + b_{ij} = c_{ij}   in time O(A(N))

Step 2. Run Algorithm C to get c_{ij} mod N in time O(C(N))
```

Repeat Steps 1 and 2  for all i,j in {0,1,...,N}.

This means that we have to repeat the steps 1,2 N^2 times. So the total run time is estimated by

```
 N^2[ O(A(N)) + O(C(N)) ] = O(N^2 A(N)) + O(N^2 C(N)) = O(|N^2 A(N)| + |(N^2 C(N)|).
```

For multiplication algorithm I just replaced step 1 by Algorithm B and got the total run time to be`O(|N^2 B(N)| + |(N^2 C(N)|)`  just like above.

Please tell me if I am approaching this problem correctly, especially with the big-O notation.

Thanks.

Comment: For matrix multiplication your algorithm is wrong. `A*B_{i,j} != A_{i,j} * B_{i,j}`, In fact, it is proven one cannot multiple matrices better than `O(n^2logn)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm for [matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Algorithms_for_efficient_matrix_multiplication) is wrong, and will yield a wrong answer, since `A*B_{i,j} != A_{i,j} * B_{i,j}` (with exception for some unique cases like zero matrix)

I assume the goal of the question is not to implement an efficient matrix multiplication, since it's a hard and still studied problem, so I will answer for the naive implementation of matrix multiplication.

For any indices i,j:

```
(AB)_{i,j} = Sum( A_{i,k} * B_{k,j}) = 
           = A_{i,1} * B_{1,j} + A_{i,2} * B_{2,j} + ... + A_{i,k} * B_{k,j} + ... + A_{i,n} * B_{n,j}
```

As you can see, for each pair `i,j` there are `n` multiplications and `n-1` additionsץ Regarding the amount of invokations of `C` - it depends if you need to invoke it after each addition, or only once when you are done (it really depends on how many bits you have to represent each number), so for each pair of `i,j` - you might need it anywhere from once to `2n-1` invokations.

This gives us total complexity of (assuming 2n-1 modolus for each (i,j) pair, if less are needed as explained above - adjust accordingly):

```
O(n^3*A + n^3*B + n^3*C)
```

As a side note, a good sanity check that shows your algorithm is indeed incorrect - it is proven that matrix multiplication cannot be done better than `Omega(n^2 logn)` ([Raz,2002](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2002/012/download/)), and best current implementation is `~O(n^2.3)`

Comment: Hey amit, Thanks a lot for your help. For the multiplication algorithm we are allowed to assume that we only have to do modulus for each 'i,j' pair once. So, would that change the complexity of the algorithm to 'O(n^2*A + n^2*B + n^2*C)'? Also, is the complexity for my addition algorithm of 'O(|N^2 A(N)| + |(N^2 C(N)|)' correct? Thanks again.

Comment: @RoseS No, it will be in this case O(n^3*A + n^3*B + n^2*C). Complexity of addition seems correct to me.

Comment: Ah yes, because we are still doing `n` multiplications and `n-1` additions for `n^2` entries. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() 
{
  int i, j;
  int a[3][3], b[3][3];

  printf("enter elements for 1 matrix\n");

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
    {
      scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  printf("enter elements for 2 matrix\n");

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
    {
      scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  printf("the sum of matrix 1 and 2\n");

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
    {
        printf("%d\n", (a[i][j] + b[i][j]));
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: firstly we declare two arrays of 3*3  and then take input from the user in the array a and b and then simply add the arrays and print them.